# Does TPM NV memory has error detecting code?

Tags: tpm

RAM and HDDs have error detecting code to detect possible bit flips due to radioactive decay of the chip or cosmic rays (soft errors). Do TPMs also have error detecting code for NV memory? It would seem logical the TPM does have error detecting code. However, I tried to Google for it and looked into TCG's resources but couldn't find anything about this. Does anyone have a source where this is described?